# Style <select> inside <form>

Tags: html, css

I have some code like this:

```
<form>
    <select name="slctr__lvl1">
        <option selected>aaa</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

I tried doing the CSS in these ways:

```
[name="slctr__lvl1"] {
    width: 150px;
}
```

and:

```
select {
    width: 150px;
}
```

and:

```
font select {
    width: 150px;
}
```

but none worked. I want it to look like I wrote:

```
<form>
    <select name="slctr__lvl1" style="width: 150px">
        <option selected>aaa</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

but the **CSS** seems to have no effect.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [CSS Attribute Selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp):

> The `[attribute="value"]` selector is used to select elements with a specified attribute and value.

Try as the following:

```css
form select[name="slctr__lvl1"] {
    width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <select name="slctr__lvl1">
        <option selected>aaa</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

You can also read further on MDN's [Attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

CSS attribute selector needs HTML tag before attribute

CSS Attribute selector
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp

CSS all selector types
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

have a look to the following example, I tried to make it work as you did, and if you compare my example with yours you will have the difference that why your code is not working

```css
select[name=slctr__lvl1] {
  background-color: yellow;
}

select{
  color: red;
}

select {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<select name="slctr__lvl1">
  <option selected>aaa</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
</select>
```

PS: I didn't understand what you want to achieve with this.

```
font select {
    width: 150px;
}
```

I think this is just a typo, You want to add `form`, not the `font` I think

Comment: oh yeah that's a typo, woop

Answer (score 0):

Give the select box a class:

```css
.selectBox{
   width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <select class="selectBox" name="slctr__lvl1">
    <option selected>aaa</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
  </select>
</form>
```